# MAC - Extract img from SD card - of actual used space

Tags: mac-osx

I have a RPI based system, which I would like to clone.

My SD card is 32 G, with 25G available space.

```
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *31.9 GB    disk1
   1:             Windows_FAT_32 boot                    64.0 MB    disk1s1
   2:                      Linux                         2.4 GB     disk1s2
   3:                      Linux                         29.4 GB    disk1s3
```

When I use `dd if=/dev/disk1 of=./my.img bs=1m`

I get a 32G img file.

My question: Is it possible to create an image of the actual used space?

Can I create an img that can be flashed to a 16G SD?

NOTE:

1. I tried `count=6000` (suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43210957/osx-truncate-sd-card-img) but it didn't work
2. The result 32G img cannot be flashed to 32G SD using Eacher since it says that the img is too big.
3. When I tried to flash the img with `dd` the RPI was not able to but with the sd.

Please help.